# nat with iptables droping access to internal network

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, iptables, nat

I want use a Raspberry Pi 3 as a AccessPoint, it has the interface wlan0 (172.24.1.1) where the people connect and eth0(192.168.1.22) connected to internal network with internet.
For to give internet access I have this rules:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE  
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wlan0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT  
iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

It rules well but I want to restrict access to wireless clients to access the internal network, in other words isolate it.

How do I do?

Thanks

Comment: Your English is a bit unclear. Are you saying you want to restrict access to wireless clients to access the internal network? In other words isolate it?

Comment: seems like what you need to do is add another rule probably on the INPUT chain to drop packets with source 172.24.1.0 to destination 192.168.1.0 EXCEPT the default gateway from where wireless gets internet. So the destination would be everything except 192.168.1.22. for this you would probably have to separate the block rule into 2 or block the whole subnet then add one more rule allowing access only to the 192.168.1.22. which ever one works